# C# XML serialize elements from type object without namespace

Tags: c#, xml, object, xml-serialization

i want to serialize the following class as child of another class.

```cs
[XmlInclude(typeof(string)), XmlInclude(typeof(XML_Variable))]
public class XMLTagDataSection
{
    [XmlElement("Offset")]
    public int XML_Offset        { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public EnuDataType XML_type  { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public object XML_Value      { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Info")]
    public string XML_Info       { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("NumBytes")]
    public int XML_NumBytes      { get; set; }
}

public class XML_Variable
{
    [XmlElement("Variable", IsNullable = false)]       
    public int   Variable { get; set; }
}
```

this is my actual output:

```xml
<Data>
  <Offset>0</Offset>
  <Type>ASCII</Type>
  <Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d7p1:type>test-string</Value>
  <Info>some text</Info>
  <NumBytes>11</NumBytes>
</Data>
<Data>
  <Offset>11</Offset>
  <Type>ASCII</Type>
  <Value d7p1:type="XML_Variable" xmlns:d7p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Variable>0</Variable>
  </Value>
  <Info>a variable</Info>
  <NumBytes>5</NumBytes>
```

how can i get rid of the namespace of my XML_Value element?
to get the following output:

```xml
<Data>
  <Offset>0</Offset>
  <Type>ASCII</Type>
  <Value>test-string</Value>
  <Info>some text</Info>
  <NumBytes>11</NumBytes>
</Data>
<Data>
  <Offset>11</Offset>
  <Type>ASCII</Type>
  <Value>
    <Variable>0</Variable>
  </Value>
  <Info>a variable</Info>
  <NumBytes>5</NumBytes>
```

i use this part of code to serialize the parent element:

```cs
XmlSerializerNamespaces NameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
NameSpace.Add("", "");

XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLRoot));

FileStream str = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);

xmlserializer.Serialize(str, Root_Tag, NameSpace);

str.Close();

return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i get rid of the namespace of my XML_Value element? to get the following output:

Easy: it doesn't have one. The namespace of an element can either be specified with an alias prefix:

```
<foo:Value ...>
```

or via the reserved `xmlns` attribute:

```
<Value xmlns="...." ...>
```

What you are referring to is the namespace qualifiers for the additional information that `XmlSerializer` **needs to deserialize that data**. It only needs it because the type is `object`, and being dutiful, it wants to be able to understand that data later - otherwise it could never ever deserialize it. One option, then, is to declare your types correctly:

```
[XmlElement("Value")]
public XML_Variable XML_Value { get; set; }
```

which will then not need this additional information.

If none of these are possible, then `XmlSerializer` *is not a good choice for you*. Consider using `XDocument` (LINQ-to-XML) or `XmlDocument` instead.

The entire point of a *serializer* is to be able to transform the data **in both directions**, and that will never be possible for `object` without additional annotations.

Comment: Thank you for the fast Response.

Comment: and there's no possibility for the XmlSerializer to seperate Tags depending on theire structure?

Comment: @user3226908 no, not really. You could implement `IXmlSerializable`, but that is frankly horrible. By the time you've done that, it would have been easier to use LINQ-to-XML or `XmlDocument`